# CSV File in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to read and fetch data from two csv files in python program parallel. One CSV file has only one column and other CSV file has 5 columns. I am getting error while reading from the one column csv file "StopIterator" error.

I am not sure whether both the CSV file has same number of row or not.

So I can't use single for loop and I want to match data row by row and note down output.

So please guide me in this.

I am using python2 version not 3.

Comment: You definitely don't have the same number of rows. Thats why you see a `StopIterator` error.

Comment: Please show the code that is giving the error

Comment: Is your data is huge ?
Can't you store data in list object ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the files in parallel, I think opening one and then the other might suffice.

```
# get content from each file
with open('file1.csv','r') as file_handle1:
    file1_content = file_handle1.read()
with open('file2.csv','r') as file_handle2:
    file2_content = file_handle2.read()

# save the content to a list per file
list_of_lines_file1 = file1_content.split('\n'):
list_of_lines_file2 = file2_content.split('\n'):

# print the two file contents line-by-line
for index in range(min(len(list_of_lines_file1),len(list_of_lines_file2))):
    print(list_of_lines_file1[index],list_of_lines_file2[index])
```